# Subwoofer high level connection and Class T amplifier

Tags: amplifier, speakers

This question has a connection to [a previous one of mine](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/495800/amplifier-speaker-outputs-is-the-black-always-the-chassis):

I have a BK Electronics Gemini I subwoofer that will soon be spare.  It has two inputs called: low level and high level.  The low level input is a pair of RCA connectors that may be connected to a suitable output of an A/V receiver.  Up to now, this is the only one that I have used.  The high level connector is a cable with a fancy connector at one end that goes to the sub and three bared wires at the other end: black, red, and yellow.  The instructions say to connect the black to the black of the left or right speaker terminal.  The red and yellow go to the red terminals of the left and right speakers. It assumes that the black terminals are common and this avoids an earth loop.  Considering the responses to my previous question, I was cautious. There is a small warning to check before using it with a Class D amplifier.

I had considered using it in a different room with a small [SMSL SA-36A amplifier](https://smile.amazon.co.uk/SMSL-SA-36A-Audio-Stereo-Amplifier-Black/dp/B017W13OR0/ref=sr_1_2?dchild=1&keywords=smsl%20sa-36a&qid=1588526335&sr=8-2).  This describes itself as [Class T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class-T_amplifier).  This appears to be a variant of a Class D.  So, I presume that I should not use this form of connection to this amplifier.

Here's the subwoofer end of the cable: [Neutrik Speakon](https://uk.farnell.com/neutrik/nl2fx/connector-speakon-socket-2pole/dp/2383461?gclid=Cj0KCQjw17n1BRDEARIsAFDHFewqCdOEaVGPG0G4gW6lNAIa2lKkLABp7AjzPDby5CADEasB4arxnHoaAt1tEALw_wcB&gross_price=true&mckv=s23ha6CAf_dc%7Cpcrid%7C432009988489%7Cplid%7C%7Ckword%7C%7Cmatch%7C%7Cslid%7C%7Cproduct%7C2383461%7Cpgrid%7C103100107409%7Cptaid%7Cpla-899098404846%7C&CMP=KNC-GUK-SHOPPING-Connectors-NEWSTRUCTURE-20APR.).

Comment: "fancy connector" is not a connector type. Photo necessary.

Comment: According to the web site, it's "High Level 100K ohm unbalanced via Neutrik Speakon connector". http://www.bkelec.com/hifi/sub_woofers/gemini.htm

Comment: Sorry, for the vagueness of "fancy connector" but the significance seemed to be that the other end was just three, not four, bare wires. Simon B is correct.

Comment: I am curious to know why this is a bad question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amplifier chips were made by Tripath who went bankrupt years ago. The output per channel is about 8W, not 20W.
Yes, the outputs of the amplifier are "bridged" with no common ground, so they cannot be connected with only 3 wires.